# docker - docker-credential-secretservice on RHEL

Tags: docker

I'm on a RHEL7.6 attempting to run

```
docker-credential-secretservice
```

I've installed it by

```
wget https://github.com/docker/docker-credential-helpers/releases/download/v0.6.0/docker-credential-secretservice-v0.6.0-amd64.tar.gz && tar -xf docker-credential-secretservice-v0.6.0-amd64.tar.gz && chmod +x docker-credential-secretservice && mv docker-credential-secretservice /usr/local/bin/
```

when i try to run it by going

```
docker-credential-secretservice
```

error:

```
docker-credential-secretservice: error while loading shared libraries: libsecret-1.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I thought the libsecret-1.so.0 wasn't installed so i installed it

```
 sudo yum install libsecret-1.so.0
```

but still gives the same error.

question

- how do i install docker-credential-secretservice?

Answer (score 11):

On Ubuntu, using apt, I had to specify:

```
sudo apt install libsecret-1-0
```

Then `docker-credential-secretservice` ran with no issue.

Answer (score 7):

To fix this issue, you need to install libsecret.

```
sudo yum install libsecret -y
```

This will install the lastest version of libsecret and you will be able to use it as a credential helper for Docker.

Once installed, you can test it with

```
docker-credential-secretservice version
```